# Why do they have multiple (basic) integral definitions (Darboux vs Riemann vs "high school")?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have gone through some mathematics books and they seem to have different definitions for integrals. For example:

- Spivak's calculus has Darboux's integral.
- Apostol's calculus has another definition (similar to Darboux's)
- There is also the Riemann integral
- And the "high-school" integral.

I was wondering how does Apostol differs from Darboux's integral and why is the Riemann integral still being taught if Darboux's is, supposedly, easier to define.

Comment: Please include the definition of each integral. (I, for one, don't know what you mean by "the 'high-school' integral". I also don't have a copy of Apostol handy.)

Comment: Isn't the Riemann integral what they teach in high school?

Comment: People don't come up with all the ideas at once. For a long time people didn't know that antiderivatives (probably what you are calling the high-school integral) were related to quadratures (areas or definite integral). Then getting better and better definitions of definite integrals has also be a process of many years. The story doesn't even end with those four, you have improper Riemann integral, Cauchy's principal value, Lebesgue integral, Denjoy-Perron integral, Henstock-Kurzweil integral, and these are not even half of what is out there. Each concept created for their own purposes.

Comment: Riemann = Darboux, each definition is useful in it own. The more general is the Riemann definition, however the Darboux definition is useful to prove some things. The details of each definition can be different from book to book but they are all equivalent.

Comment: Riemann ... upper and lower sums; Darboux .... sums where you evaluate the function at "some point" in the interval.  There is an appendix in one of Spivak's chapters where he shows the two are equivalent definitions.  And then it is just called "Riemann integral".